# How do I make this HTML form work?

Tags: php, html, forms, contacts

I have a website template that I am working on, and it includes a contact form in HTML. I am having a hard time getting it to send the form contents in an email. I tried creating the PHP script to do so, but I'm just not having any luck. Any help would really be appreciated!

Here is the form HTML code:

```html
<form action="" class="main_form error" novalidate target="_blank">
  <label class="form-group">
    <span class="fa fa-asterisk"></span>
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your name here" data-validation-required-message="Please, enter Your name" required />
    <span class="help-block text-danger"></span>
  </label>
  <label class="form-group">
    <span class="fa fa-asterisk"></span>
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your E-mail here" data-validation-required-message="Your E-mail isn't correct" required />
    <span class="help-block text-danger"></span>
  </label>
  <label class="form-group">
    <span class="fa fa-asterisk"></span>
    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Your message here" data-validation-required-message="Please, type Your message" required></textarea>
    <span class="help-block text-danger"></span>
  </label>
  <button>Send it to me</button>
</form>
```

Comment: add  your php script. tell us what you have done so far.

Comment: You can read about form sending in php [here](http://www.freecontactform.com/email_form.php)

Answer (score 0):

We need the following files:

1. form.html (the page with form)
2. form_processing.php (the file with the script that handles the HTML form.)

---

You only have to expose your data.

**HTML**

```html
<title>Some form</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="form_processing.php" method="post">
<p>Your name:<br /><input type="text" name="your_name" /></p>
<p>E-mail:<br /><input type="text" name="email" /></p>
<p>Title:<br /><input type="text" name="title" /></p>
<p>Message: <br />
<textarea name="message" rows="5" cols="45"> </textarea></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
/* Carry out the checking of the input data and their protection from hostile scripts. */
$your_name = htmlspecialchars($_POST["your_name"]);
$email = htmlspecialchars($_POST["email"]);
$title = htmlspecialchars($_POST["title"]);
$message = htmlspecialchars($_POST["messages"]);

/* Set e-mail recipient */
$myemail = "my_email@mail.ru";

/* Check the full mandatory input fields */
$your_name = check_input($_POST["your_name"], "Enter your name!");
$title = check_input($_POST["title"], "Specify the subject");
$email = check_input($_POST["email"], "Enter your e-mail!");
$message = check_input($_POST["message"], "You forgot to write the message!");

/* Create a new variable by assigning a value to */
$message_to_myemail = "Hello! 
Your contact form sent message! 
Sender name: $your_name 
E-mail: $email 
Text: $message 
End";

/* Send the message using mail() function */
$from  = "From: $yourname <$email> \r\n Reply-To: $email \r\n"; 
mail($myemail, $title, $message_to_myemail, $from);
?>
<p>Your message has been successfully sent!</p>
<p>Go <a href="index.php">Home >>></a></p>
<?php

/* If when filling out the form mistakes were made the following code will work: */
function check_input($data, $problem = "") {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);

    if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0) {
    show_error($problem);
    }
    return $data;
    }
}

function show_error($myError) {
    // Some code
}

?>
<html>
    <body>
        <p>Please correct the following error:</p>
        <?php echo $myError; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

My first try to help, hope this will be of some use.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HEAD>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<TITLE>Contact</TITLE>
<style>
#form  {width : 500px;
        border-style : solid;
        border-width : 3px;
        border-color : blue;  }

</style>
<script type="text/javascript"> 

function send_message (){  

   var onoma = document.getElementById("Name").value;
   var mail = document.getElementById("email").value;
   var Theme = document.getElementById("subject").value;
   var keim = document.getElementById("Texts").value;

   var mail_link = "mailto:your_email?subject=From Site         :"+Theme+"&body="+keim; 
   var win = window.open(mail_link, 'emailWindow');  
}
</script>

</HEAD>
<BODY>
<center>
<div id="form">
<pre>
  Name : <input type="text" id="Name"><br>
E-mail : <input type="email" id="email"><br>
Subject: <input type="text" id="subject"><br>
         <textarea height="80" width="200" id="keimeno"></textarea>
</pre>
<button onclick="send_message()">Send it</button>
</div>
</pre>
</FORM>
</center>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Since you're not showing any of your PHP code, I might be telling you things you already know about.]

### 1. Get the form contents to the server

Forms can be submitted using (usually) GET or POST requests. Which method to use is determined by the method attribute in the <form> element. E.g *<form method="get">*. The default is GET, so since you haven't specified a method in your form code that's what you'll be using. GET requests append the data to the URL after a question mark, e.g *mysite.com/form.php?var1=val1&var2=val2&...* As you probably imagine this will probably get really unwieldy if the data is somewhat other than small. And also, there's a length limit. Though there are other things to consider as well, GET requests aren't suitable for "large" requests.

Enter POST: This way the URL will be left untouched, and the data will be sent "behind the "scenes". (Read up on HTTP protocol for details)

The only thing you need to change in your form is the method attribute as previously mentioned, everything else will look the same regardless of method. (In this case, if you're submitting files or so things start getting more complicated)

### 2. Process the request that has arrived to the server using PHP

When PHP processes GET or POST requests the data is placed in reserved arrays called $_GET and $_POST respectively. The indexes are the names of the input elements in your HTML code, i.e 'name', 'email' and 'message'. So either $_GET['name'] or $_POST['name'] to get the user's name.
**You should make sure that the data submitted is legit. Never trust user submitted data!**

### 3. Use some way in PHP to send your mail.

This can be a builtin function:

mail(to, subject, message)

```
mail($recipient_email, 'my subject', $_GET['message']);
```

..in this case. Please do note that it'll take some configuration work to make PHP know where to send the mail :).

..or a package like PHPMailer.

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->setFrom($_GET['email'], $_GET['name']);
$mail->addAddress('your email', 'Your name'); // Add a recipient

$mail->isHTML(true); // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Contact form subject';
$mail->Body    = $_GET['message'];

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

Again:

- You should most likely use POST requests for contact forms.
- Do *NOT* trust user data.

Good luck :).

Comment: Thank you for all of the help guys! I was able to build a php script to execute the form using the examples that you guys gave. Everything works fine!